# Inserting timestamps into Excel

Tags: excel

I need to format a number to be displayed as timestamp in Excel.
For example, this number 2083249 is being displayed as 2.083.249 but it represents a timestamp so I want it to be displayed as 2,083249.

Is there any way to format it to the desired format (2,083249)? It's quite a lot of data to be done manually.

Some additional information (not sure if relevant):
The timestamps come from wireshark, which I exported to CSV and in the CSV file they are being displayed as 2.083249 but then when imported to excel they end up being 2.083.249.

Many thanks for all the help.

Edited:
After playing around with the CSV file a bit I have managed to format the cell while importing from the CSV file into excel. Now it's displaying as 2,83249 but isn't displaying the last zero. It should be 2,832490. Any suggestion?

Comment: just use formatting of the cell?!

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a CSV for import into Excel, write the date formatted as a date string (e.g. '2010-06-24'), otherwise write a genuine Excel file where you can actually set the formatting of cells.

2,083249 is not a timestamp format

Comment: The problem is that I'm exporting the CSV from wireshark data which displays the 'timestamp' as 2,083249. I think I used the wrong terminology. It isn't a timestamp, in fact it's such a time difference represented in seconds. To be more precise is the seconds between the arrival of two different packets.

Comment: Because the time difference is greater than a day, you're going to need a format mask to display hours:minutes:seconds... you probably need to write a real Excel file using any library appropriate to your choice of language that allows you to set format masks

Answer (score 1):

there's something called custom tags in the "format cell" tab. you can create you own cell format.

- Right click on the cell which containing the number 2083249
- then press the tab "Number" and select the last box "Custom"
- in the textbar under title "Type: " put this format 0","######
- press 'ok'
- scroll to let all other cells format with the new style

note: be sure that all the numbers within cells have the same length (i.e 2083249 is 7 digits then all the other cells contain 7 digits)